# PHP array match MYSQL string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a color array and want to match the color row in MYSQL,

as long as the color row match one of the colors in array, then take it out.

the following `$colorArray` should match id 2 & 3, because those rows contain yellow & blue

```
$colorArray = array('yellow','blue');

+------+---------+------------+
| id   | product | color      |
+------+---------+------------+
|    1 | tShirt  | red,green  |
|    2 | jeans   | yellow,red |
|    3 | shorts  | black,blue |
+------+---------+------------+
```

I just want a MySQL SELECT syntax, I know it can be done with PHP `array_intersect` to do some filters, but I don't want to for some reasons.

So is it possible?

Comment: What kind of field is 'color'?

Comment: yes, it's a String (varchar)

Comment: I believe @AdelBachene's answer will work for you. Just the change `$sql` part from `$sql = "DELETE FROM <your_table_name> WHERE REGEXP '".$colorsStr."'";` to `$sql = "SELECT * FROM <your_table_name> WHERE REGEXP '".$colorsStr."'";`

Comment: have you tried my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FIND_IN_SET() in your query .Try this let me know. I hope I sloved your problem
your required query

```
SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('yellow', colour) or FIND_IN_SET('blue', colour)
```

code:

```
<?php
$colorArray = array('yellow','blue','red');
$where1 ="FIND_IN_SET('$colorArray[0]', colour) ";
$where="";
for($i=1;$i<sizeof($colorArray);$i++){
$color=$colorArray[$i];
$where .= "  or FIND_IN_SET('$color', colour) ";
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE $where1 $where";
//echo $sql;//SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('yellow', colour) or FIND_IN_SET('blue', colour) or FIND_IN_SET('red', colour) 
// try running this query 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having a problem in combining an `in` and a `Like %S%`, so
A [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) might be more efficient, but you'd have to benchmark it to be sure, e.g.

```
$colorsStr = implode('|', $colorArray); // => 'yellow|blue'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM <your_table_name> WHERE REGEXP '" . $colorsStr . "'";
```

Comment: OP wants to `SELECT` the rows, not `DELETE` the rows.

Comment: @Adel Bachene thanks, but i 'm not familiar with REGEXP orz

Answer (score 1):

It is easy:

```
<?php
$color = array('yellow', 'red');
$query = "";
foreach($color as $c)
   $query .= "color like '%".$c."%' or ";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM <your_table_name> WHERE ".$query." 1=0";
?>
```

Comment: U will get the OR in last iteration

Comment: And OP Need this in mysql not want to use php

Comment: final query is: SELECT * FROM <your_table_name> WHERE color like '%red%' or color like '%yellow%' or 1=0 and has no problem.

Comment: @devpro Comment2: because of there are order in your data, another solutions in sql has very overhead. I suggest use PHP or change structure in sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$colorsStr = implode(',', $colorArray); // => 'yellow,blue'
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM <your_table_name> WHERE color IN('.$colorsStr.')';
```

Comment: Then try this: `$sql = 'SELECT id FROM <your_table_name> WHERE color = \''.$colorsStr.'\'';`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
$colorArray = array('yellow','blue');
$colors = join(',',$colorArray);  
$sql = "SELECT '$colors' AS colors,
       color,
       CONCAT('(', REPLACE(color, ',', '(\\,|$)|'), '(\\,|$))') AS regex,
       '$colors' REGEXP CONCAT('(', REPLACE(color, ',', '(\\,|$)|'), '(\\,|$))') AS intersect
       FROM YourTableName
       GROUP BY id HAVING intersect > 0";
```

Comment: @Taniel I asked you what kind of field is color. Can you answer please?

Comment: THANKS !! let me try later, you're very kind to help me : )

Answer (score 0):

```
$colorArray = array('yellow','blue');
$colors = implode(",",$colorArray);  
$query = "SELECT color FROM TableName WHERE color = '.$colors.'";
```

Comment: Can u try this yur self?

Comment: U r initizing colors variable and using color variable

Comment: Please add some explanations.